# How is a boolean saved in a database? Is it a special String?

Tags: database, string, excel, integer, boolean

If you download a Excel file from your Database then "true" or "false" is saved as String. Does it look the same in a Database or are the Booleans converted to Strings for the Excel-Sheet? 
If the booleans aren't saved as "String" (String with special properties) in a database: How are they saved, as integer (like 0 and 1)?

Comment: That really depends on the database but usually booleans are just special representations of integers (0 is false, everything else is true)

Comment: some platforms don't have native support for a true boolean type so you have to roll your own

Comment: Database dependent, please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is database dependent, I'll provide the best possible answer for an unknown.

In mysql:

> Bool, Boolean: These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of
>   zero is considered false. Non-zero values are considered true.

Otherwise, you can use TINYINT or bit datatype.

TINYINT is support by the vast majority of databases also.